# javascript match func always return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a live search and i code below code but match does not work correctly when i text some input into my input form i get always empty string. What is the problem?

```
const handleChange = (e) => {  //HANDLE FUNCTION FOR CHANGES. I TESTED IT. IT WORK CORRECTLY
    e.preventDefault();
    setinput(e.target.value);
  };

  let k = [...songs]; //I TESTED THAT THAT IS WORK CORRECTLY. IT GIVES THE REACK HOOK VALUE TO K VAR.

  if (input.length > 0) { // IF SOME INPUT TYPED IT CONTROL THAT
    k = k.filter((i) => { // BUT THIS METHOD ALWAYS RETURN NULL
      i.song_name.match(input);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search song"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={input}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="playlist">
        {k.map((song) => (
          <li key={song.song_id} className="Upbox">
            <SongRow track={song} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

FOR TEST PURPOSE MY 3 STRİNGS ARE:

```
"Artistless Song"
"Small Mountain"
"Core of Nature"
```

For example when i typed "Ar" to my input field it should give me "Artistless Song" but it return null.

Comment: You need to return in your filter callback. Right now you're not returning anything, which means the callback returns undefined. Try `return i.song_name.match(input);`

Comment: try `return  i.song_name.match(input);`

Comment: My god. I don't believe that. I spended 2 hours for that. Thanks. @Terry

Comment: get a linter for your IDE

Comment: @LeoS No problem. I've added an answer that further elabourates on my comment. Chances are, you might have gotten used to implicit returns in ES6 (I've done that a few times, too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further elabourate on my comment: you are missing a `return` keyword in your `Array.prototype.filter` callback. Without a return statement, the filter will always return `undefined`, which will return an empty array.

```
if (input.length > 0) {
    k = k.filter((i) => {
        // Remember to return!
        return i.song_name.match(input);
    });
}
```

I have a feeling you forgot the return statement because in ES6, it is indeed possible to [return an expression inside arrow functions without the `return` statement, but if and only if a simple statement is used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body). In that case, you need to remove the curly brackets for the callback to return implicitly, i.e.:

```
if (input.length > 0) {
    // Implicit return
    k = k.filter((i) => i.song_name.match(input));
}
```